# How do you split a string by periods, but not the ones used in titles like Mr or Mrs?

Tags: c++, split

As part of a school project, I have to write code to read a file and split it into sentences. I decided to use the strtok method using periods, question marks, and exclamation points as delimiters, which almost works. The problem is, if the input file has periods in the middle of sentences, like with prefix titles, my code treats those as delimiters as well. What I need is a solution that will split a string by periods while ignoring the periods in Mr., Mrs., Ms., and Dr. specifically.

This is the code I wrote:

```
std::string buffer;

    while(fileRead)
    {
        std::getline(fileRead, buffer);
        char *temp = new char[buffer.length() + 1];
        strcpy(temp, buffer.c_str());
        char *q = std::strtok(temp, ".?!");

        while(q != NULL)
        {
            std::cout << q << std::endl;
            q = strtok(NULL, ".?!");
        }

    }
```

For the most part, this works fine, save for the spaces after periods. The problem is, if the input file has something like

```
I am Mr. Smith.
```

My code outputs

```
I am Mr  
Smith
```

Whereas I want it to output

```
I am Mr. Smith
```

Comment: First of all, you need a dictionary to achieve this accurately.

Comment: What, you mean there's too many possible titles? I really only need to account for Mr, Mrs, Ms, and Dr. This is only a school assignment, after all.

Comment: Then edit this info into the question and clarify your request.

Comment: I've just edited the question. Will this be okay?

Comment: Wouldn't the split sentences include the punctuation? You could just read word by word and output a newline if the last character is punctuation and the whole word doesn't match one of the titles.

Comment: Related mandatory read: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you've recently learned how to read whitespace-separated words with `>>`.

Comment: Although it does not affect this homework assignment, I wonder about things like this: `Are there any sentences that properly end with Mr.?` or, `The previous sentence properly ends with Mr.` Adding quotes introduces its own complications: `... properly ends with "Mr."`.

Comment: Messrs. William Strunk Jr. and E. B. White disapprove this question.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the end of a sentence is a difficult task. To do it properly requires a deep understanding of grammar and language structure. Simply marking the locations of periods, question marks, and exclamation points will not do.

Nevertheless, in a homework assignment, finding those punctuation marks may be all that is expected. Tossing in a check for common abbreviations, such as *Mr.*, *Ms.*, and so on, makes the results a bit more credible.

##### Data file: `sentences.txt`

The data file used by the program below contains a few abbreviations, as well as some sentences that will not be detected correctly. All of the sentences in the first paragraph parse just fine, but the rest of them cause problems.

In the data file, each paragraph appears on a single line, but I am letting the lines word-wrap here, so that they can be read easily.

Here is file `sentences.txt`:

As part of a school project, I have to write code to read a file and split it into sentences. I decided to use the strtok method using periods, question marks, and exclamation points as delimiters, which almost works. The problem is, if the input file has periods in the middle of sentences, like with prefix titles, my code treats those as delimiters as well. What I need is a solution that will split a string by periods while ignoring the periods in Mr., Mrs., Ms., and Dr. specifically.

Can a sentence properly end with Mr.? Yes, for example, the previous sentence ends with Mr. The situation gets a bit trickier when you throw in quotes.

For example: Please don't call me "Mr." My program will have trouble with this example!

Another example with quotes: She said, "Hello." The closing quote should not be part of the next sentence!

(Parenthesized sentences have the same problem.) The closing parenthesis should not be part of the next sentence.

There are other tricky situations... like when you use three periods in a row as an ellipsis.

##### A program to extract sentences

The program below builds a sentence by appending one character at a time to string `s`. After a period is appended to `s`, the program calls function `ends_with_abbr` to check whether the period should be treated as the end of a sentence, or merely the end of an abbreviation.

```cpp
bool ends_with_abbr(std::string const& s)
{
    static const std::vector<std::string> abbr
    {
        "Mr.", "Ms.", "Mrs.", "No.", "Dr.", "Sr.", "Jr.", "St.", "Ste."
    };
    for (auto const& a : abbr)
        if (s.ends_with(a))
            return true; 
    return false;
}
```

As suggested in the data file, this approach will fail when an abbreviation appears at the end of a sentence. Nevertheless, that is the approach we use.

Given function `ends_with_abbr`, detecting the end of a sentence is straightforward. In this test, variable `c` holds a character that has just been pushed onto the back of string `s`:

```cpp
        if (c == '.' && !ends_with_abbr(s) || c == '?' || c == '!')
            break;  // We found the end of a sentence.
```

Function `get_sentence` reads the next sentence from input stream `ist`. In this program, `ist` is the data file, i.e., it is a `std::ifstream` object. It could, however, be any other type of input stream, such as a stringstream, or even `std::cin` (if you know how to input an `eof` character from the keyboard!).

Function `get_sentence` reads characters in a loop, appending them to string `s`, and stopping when it detects the end of a sentence. It returns `true` when it has successfully input a non-empty sentence, and `false` when it finds only whitespace remaining in the file, before it hits end-of-file.

```cpp
bool get_sentence(std::istream& ist, std::string& s)
{
    if (ist.good())
        ist >> std::ws;
    s.clear();
    char c;
    while (ist.get(c))
    {
        s.push_back(c);
        if (c == '.' && !ends_with_abbr(s) || c == '?' || c == '!')
            break;
    }
    return !s.empty();
}
```

Function `get_sentences` (plural) accepts an input stream, `ist`, and an output stream, `ost`, as arguments. As above, `ist` can be any type of input stream. In this program, `ist` is the data file. Similarly, `ost`, can be any type of output stream, including a file or stringstream. In this program, `ost` is `std::cout`.

Function `get_sentences` successively inputs sentences from `ist` and outputs them, double-spaced, to `ost`. It stops when function `get_sentence` returns `false`, indicating that no more sentences can be read.

```cpp
void get_sentences(std::istream& ist, std::ostream& ost)
{
    enum : std::string::size_type { initial_capacity = 128u };
    std::string s;
    s.reserve(initial_capacity);
    while (get_sentence(ist, s))
        ost << s << "\n\n";
}
```

The only thing missing is function `main`, which opens the file, and calls function `get_sentences` to get things going. Here is the complete program:

```cpp
// main.ixx
export module main;
import std;

bool ends_with_abbr(std::string const& s)
{
    static const std::vector<std::string> abbr
    {
        "Mr.", "Ms.", "Mrs.", "No.", "Dr.", "Sr.", "Jr.", "St.", "Ste."
    };
    for (auto const& a : abbr)
        if (s.ends_with(a))
            return true; 
    return false;
}
bool get_sentence(std::istream& ist, std::string& s)
{
    if (ist.good())
        ist >> std::ws;
    s.clear();
    char c;
    while (ist.get(c))
    {
        s.push_back(c);
        if (c == '.' && !ends_with_abbr(s) || c == '?' || c == '!')
            break;
    }
    return !s.empty();
}
void get_sentences(std::istream& ist, std::ostream& ost)
{
    enum : std::string::size_type { initial_capacity = 128u };
    std::string s;
    s.reserve(initial_capacity);
    while (get_sentence(ist, s))
        ost << s << "\n\n";
}
export int main()
{
    int exit_code{};
    std::string data_file("sentences.txt");
    std::ifstream ist{ data_file };
    std::ostream& ost{ std::cout };
    if (ist.is_open())
        get_sentences(ist, ost);
    else
    {
        ost << "Could not open data file \"" 
            << data_file 
            << "\".\n\n";
        exit_code = 1;
    }
    return exit_code;
}
// end file: main.ixx
```

And this is the output:

```
As part of a school project, I have to write code to read a file and split it into sentences.

I decided to use the strtok method using periods, question marks, and exclamation points as delimiters, which almost works.

The problem is, if the input file has periods in the middle of sentences, like with prefix titles, my code treats those as delimiters as well.

What I need is a solution that will split a string by periods while ignoring the periods in Mr., Mrs., Ms., and Dr. specifically.

Can a sentence properly end with Mr.?

Yes, for example, the previous sentence ends with Mr. The situation gets a bit trickier when you throw in quotes.

For example: Please don't call me "Mr." My program will have trouble with this example!

Another example with quotes: She said, "Hello.

" The closing quote should not be part of the next sentence!

(Parenthesized sentences have the same problem.

) The closing parenthesis should not be part of the next sentence.

There are other tricky situations.

.

.

like when you use three periods in a row as an ellipsis.
```

Answer (score -1):

std::endl adds the line break. So you can backtrack and check if your just printed string ends in one of your titles. If so, don't print the line break. Basically manually implementing the negative look behind. I'm sure you can take it from here.

Comment: Except at that point, there's no way to know whether it ended in `.` or not, since that was eaten by `strtok`. Well, there's a copy of the string. But this is a roundabout way of doing it, since it's almost the same as just parsing the sentence to begin with.

Comment: @paddy You can always just use a regular loop and check if the current character is one of your candidates `.!?`. If so, you can easily check the previous one by simple pointer arithmetic. If you get stuck, edit your question accordingly and leave a comment so I get a notification

Comment: I didn't ask the question. Just making the observation that to utilize this approach, you may as well write the tokenizer as well. Otherwise it's just awkward.

Comment: Although it is probably not an issue for this homework assignment, another problem involves sentences that end with a quote mark, such as: `He said, "I am Mr. Smith."` Perhaps less of an issue is parenthesized sentences. (I am referring to complete sentences only.)

Comment: @tbxfreeware and then there's trailing of sentences...

Answer (score -1):

So, with help from everyone's answers, I've decided to forego strtok() entirely and instead read the file line by line, then read each line character by character. In the end, it looks something like this:

```
bool valid(std::string s)
{
    std::string words[] = {"Mr.", "Dr.", "No.", "Ms.", "Mrs."};
    for(std::string &word: words)
    {
        if(s.compare(word) == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void Reader::read()
{
    char *q;
    std::string buffer;

    while(std::getline(fileRead, buffer))
    {
        q = new char[buffer.length() + 1];
        strcpy(q, buffer.c_str());

        char *qi = q;

        //bool endit = false;

        while(qi <= q + buffer.length())
        {
            std::cout << *qi;
            if(*qi == '.')
            {
                std::string test(qi - 2, 3);

                if(!valid(test))
                {
                    std::cout << std::endl;
                    qi++;
                }
            }
            qi++;
        }

        if(*(qi - 2) != '.')
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

    }

}
```

Still a few issues to iron out, but these I can take care of. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Whoops! There is a memory leak. I see `new`, without any correspoinding `delete`. Why use a C-string at all? There is no need for manual memory allocation or for pointers. Instead, you should use string iterators to a C++ string, e.g.: `auto it = s.begin();`, `if (*it == '.')...` and `while (it != s.end())...`.

Comment: Honestly? I’ve never used iterators before, so I kind of just used everything that was already in my toolbox, so to speak.

Comment: Yup. Iterators are designed to look like and work like pointers. Try this out: `std::string s = "Hello, World!"; for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it) std::cout << *it << '\n';`

Comment: You can also treat a `std::string` like an array of `char`, when that suits you. This loop searches for `'.'`, and changes it to `'!'`: `std::string s = "Hello, World."; for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) { if (s[i] == '.') s[i] = '!'; std::cout << s[i] << '\n'; }`

Comment: Here is the same loop, but with an iterator: `std::string s = "Hello, World."; for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it) { if (*it == '.') *it = '!'; std::cout << *it << '\n'; }`

Comment: C++20 added a handy member function to class `std::string` named `ends_with`. Using it, you might create function `ends_with_abbr`, a function which could be used in an if-statement to check whether a string ends with an any of the abbreviations that concern you. `bool ends_with_abbr(std::string const& s) { static const std::vector<std::string> abbr{ "Mr.", "Ms.", "Mrs.", "No.", "Dr." }; for (auto const& a : abbr) if (s.ends_with(a)) return true; return false; }`

Answer (score -1):

Conceptually, you're splitting on the regex pattern `(?<!Mr?)\.`, which means:

> `.` which is not following `Mr` or `Mrs`

Unfortunately, the C++ `<regex>` library does not support (negative) lookbehind, so you'll need to make something from scratch.

#### C++17 Template-Based Solution

The idea behind my approach is to go through the string character by character and split on each `.`. However, the strings `Mr.` and `Mrs.` are skipped completely so the `.` in them isn't treated specially.

```cpp
// note: prior to C++17, write const std::string& instead of using std::string_view
template <typename Consumer>
void for_each_part(Consumer consumer, std::string_view str) {
    std::size_t part_start = 0;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); ) {
        if (str.substr(i, 3) == "Mr.") {
            i += 3;
        }
        else if (str.substr(i, 4) == "Mrs.") {
            i += 4;
        }
        else if (str[i] == '.') {
            consumer(str.substr(part_start, i - part_start));
            part_start = i + 1;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (part_start != str.length()) {
        consumer(str.substr(part_start));
    }
}
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/8MTserWKx)*

#### Usage

```cpp
std::getline(fileRead, buffer);
for_each_part([](std::string_view part) {
    std::cout << part << '\n';
}, buffer);
```

#### Further Notes

It's not strictly necessary to make this a function template.
You could also accept a `std::vector<std::string_view>&` and `.push_back` to this vector instead of invoking the `consumer`.

However, this would be less flexible because it would force you to use `std::vector`, and you can easily push to a vector with the template solution like

```cpp
std::vector<std::string_view> parts; // or std::string prior to C++17
for_each_part([](std::string_view part) {
    parts.push_back(part);
}, buffer);
```

Answer (score -2):

One common option in programming is to fix something afterwards, if it's hard to do it right up front.

In your case, you can glue two lines together when the first line ends in `Mr.`. This means you don't write `<< std::endl` when a line ends in `Mr.`

Answer (score -4):

Since you tagged your question as a C++ one I will answer in C++.

```
std::string buffer;
std::string::const_reverse_iterator tmp;
while (std::getline(fileRead, buffer)) {
    for (tmp = buffer.crbegin(); tmp != buffer.crend() && std::ispunct(*tmp); ++tmp) {}
    std::copy(buffer.cbegin(), tmp.base(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>{ std::cout });
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Let's take "I am Mr. Smith." as an example.
tmp is used to find out the address of the off-the-punctuation character. When you fall through the for cycle tmp will point to the character 'h'.
tmp.base() is used to return a const_iterator which will point to the character '.'.
copy is used to output the characters of buffer which belong to the range ['I'; '.') character by character.
For std::ispunct you have to `#include <cctype>`

Comment: This code removes *punctuation* at the end of every input *line*. It has nothing to do whatsoever with what OP is asking.